# AngularJS dynamic custom directive issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My custom directive runs fine onload page load but when added using append it does not run properly. It does not show its content when at in runtime.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="module1">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">    

  <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>    
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="divContainer" style="border-style: solid;border-color:red;" ng-controller = "Controller1 as cnt1" >
    <button ng-click="clicked();">Click Me!!</button> 
    <wlaccordion></wlaccordion>
</div>        

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('module1',[]);

app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.authorData = authorInfo;

    $scope.clicked = function () {
        alert('Clicked');
        //angular.element(document.getElementById('divContainer')).append('<wlaccordion1></wlaccordion1>' (scope));
        angular.element(document.getElementById('divContainer')).append('<wlaccordion></wlaccordion>');
    }

}]);//controller1    

var authorInfo = [
    {
        'name': 'Ray',
        'rate': '10',
        'show': 'true'    
    },
    {
        'name': 'Mahesh',
        'rate': '12',        
        'show': 'true'    
    }
]

app.directive("wlaccordion", function($compile) {

    var template = '<div ng-controller = "Controller1 as cnt1">' +   
                        '<div ng-repeat="aData in authorData" ng-init="tab = 1">' +    
                            '<ul>' +
                                '<li>' +
                                    '<h1 ng-show={{aData.show}} ng-class="{active: tab === 1}"> {{aData.name}} </h1>' +                
                                    '<h1 ng-show={{aData.show}} ng-class="{active: tab === 2}"> {{aData.rate | currency}} </h1>' +
                                '</li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';            

    return{
        link: function(scope, element){
                    var content = $compile(template)(scope);
                    element.append(content);
        }
    }
});
```

I would like the directive to function same as onload.

-Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: `.append` is a very un-Angular thing to do. You should use `ng-if` to toggle your accordion instead

Comment: @RGraham I will be getting fresh data in JSON format based on which I need to rebuild the view. Right now I have just put static data.

Comment: Why are you compiling the code in `link` function instead of using template property of directive?

Comment: I tried various combinations, none worked, even this one does not work when added element is appended.

I just need a way to show the <wlaccordion> directive using element append as it shows on document load.

Comment: You can't just append a directive. It needs to be compiled (check out $compile: code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/service/$compile). That said, @RGraham is correct. Don't manipulate the DOM in your controller!!! code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/guide/controller. Use a built in directive such as ng-include or ng-if, or create your own.

Comment: I had used template property but the ng-repeat would not fire in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS intended for separation of presentation logic and business one. So I think you should do this in Angular way, your current approach is more jQuery one.

I would suggest you to add accordions collection to controller:

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.accordions = [0]; // Replace 0 with some actual data
    $scope.clicked = function() {
        $scope.accordions.push($scope.accordions.length); // Same here
    };
    // Your other code
}
```

And in HTML add `ng-repeat`:

```
<div id="divContainer" style="border-style: solid;border-color:red;" ng-controller = "Controller1 as cnt1" >
    <button ng-click="clicked();">Click Me!!</button> 
    <wlaccordion ng-repeat="accordion in accordions"></wlaccordion>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Also don't forget to remove compilation from `wlaccordion`'s `link`.

**Edit #2:** I suppose that `authorInfo` global var is used simply for example, however if it doesn't then consider usage of `module.constant` or `module.value`

Comment: Thanks, I'll restructure my code. What I am wondering is why the custom directive not showing up properly even though $compile was used without link.

Comment: Because that `link` function was never executed - angluar had no idea that you've added that directive (because you've made it through jQuery). You should've executed compilation in parent code: `angular.element(...).append($compile('<wlaccordion/>')($scope))`. Just to make it clear: angular have no idea about **any** DOM manipulation you are doing through jQuery.

Comment: when I do that I get exception: ReferenceError: $compile is not defined

Comment: Do you have it declared in controller's dependencies?

Comment: Finally got it working, Thanks for your help. Dependency was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('Controller1', ['$scope','$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.authorData = authorInfo;

    $scope.clicked = function () {
        alert('Clicked');
        //angular.element(document.getElementById('divContainer')).append('<wlaccordion1></wlaccordion1>' (scope));
        angular.element(document.getElementById('divContainer')).append($compile('<wlaccordion></wlaccordion>')($scope));
    }

}]);//controller1
```